# Screen scraping with HTMLAgility help please

Tags: c#, .net, sql, database, web-scraping

Last night when I asked about screen scraping I was given an excellent article link and has got me to this point. I have a few questions however. I will post my code as well as the html source below. I am trying to grab the data between the data tables, and then send the data to an sql table. I have found success in grabbing Description Widget 3.5 ect... Last Modified By Joe however because the 1st 2 /tr also contains img src=/......" alt="00721408" the numbers do not get grabbed. I am stuck as to how to alter the code so that all the data in the table is grabbed. 2nd, What do I need to do next in order to prepare the data to be sent to a sql table. My code is as follows:

```
using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.Linq;
        using System.Text;
        using HtmlAgilityPack;
        using System.Windows.Forms;

        namespace ConsoleApplication1
        {

        }
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                // Load the html document
                var webGet = new HtmlWeb();
                var doc = webGet.Load("http://localhost");

                // Get all tables in the document
                HtmlNodeCollection tables = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table");

                // Iterate all rows in the first table
                HtmlNodeCollection rows = tables[0].SelectNodes(".//tr");
                for (int i = 0; i < rows.Count; ++i)
                {
                    // Iterate all columns in this row
                    HtmlNodeCollection cols = rows[i].SelectNodes(".//td");
                    for (int j = 0; j < cols.Count; ++j)
                    {

                        // Get the value of the column and print it
                        string value = cols[j].InnerText;

                        Console.WriteLine(value);


                    }
                }

            }
        }





<table class="data">




<tr><td>Part-Num</td><td width="50"></td><td><img src="/partcode/number/072140" alt="072140"/></td></tr>




<tr><td>Manu-Number</td><td width="50"></td><td><img src="/partcode/manu/00721408" alt="00721408" /></td></tr>

<tr><td>Description</td><td></td><td>Widget 3.5</td></tr>



<tr><td>Manu-Country</td><td></td><td>United States</td></tr>

<tr><td>Last Modified</td><td></td><td>26 Jan 2011,  8:08 PM</td></tr>


<tr><td>Last Modified By</td><td></td><td>
Manu

</td></tr>




</table>



<p>


</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While fragile something like this would work in your case - basically just including the text content of all image `alt` attributes:

```
// Iterate all rows in the first table
HtmlNodeCollection rows = tables[0].SelectNodes(".//tr");
for (int i = 0; i < rows.Count; ++i)
{
    // Iterate all columns in this row
    HtmlNodeCollection cols = rows[i].SelectNodes(".//td");
    for (int j = 0; j < cols.Count; ++j)
    {
        var images = cols[j].SelectNodes("img");
        if(images!=null)
            foreach (var image in images)
            {
                if(image.Attributes["alt"]!=null)
                    Console.WriteLine(image.Attributes["alt"].Value);
            }
        // Get the value of the column and print it
        string value = cols[j].InnerText;
        Console.WriteLine(value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a litte confused as to what data you're trying to obtain however...

you could try:

SelectNodes("//td[text()='Description']/../child::*[3]")

whose inner text should be "Widget 3.5"

SelectNodes("//td[text()='Manu-Country']/../child::*[3]")

whose inner text should be "United States"

etc. etc.

Btw just as a shameless plug, you should check out : [systemhtml.codeplex.com](http://systemhtml.codeplex.com)
It's yet another html parser.

Comment: I will look at systemhtml. Yes you are correct I want to take the inner text "widget 3.5 United states ect and send them to a sql table with fields Description, Manu-Country ect.